# Sequelize Alter always set all data table foreign key to null

Tags: node.js, sqlite, express, sequelize.js

### Bug Description

after running sequelize sync with options `alter: true`, all foreign keys in tables set to `null`.

```js
await sequelize.sync({ alter: true }).then(async (result) => {
      await initDataUserGroup();
      await initDataUserAdmin();
      await initDataGateType();
});
```

and here my one model which has foreign key :

```js
const { DataTypes } = require("sequelize");
const { sequelize } = require("../services/DatabaseService");

const UserGroup = require("./UserGroup");
const Biodata = require("./Biodata");

const User = sequelize.define("user", {
  username: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    allowNull: false,
    unique: true,
    validate: {
      notNull: {
        msg: "Username must not be empty",
      },
      notEmpty: true,
    },
  },
  email: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    allowNull: false,
    unique: true,
    validate: {
      notNull: true,
      notEmpty: true,
      isEmail: true,
    },
  },
  password: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    allowNull: false,
    validate: {
      notNull: true,
      notEmpty: true,
    },
  },
});

User.UserGroup = User.belongsTo(UserGroup);
User.Biodata = User.hasOne(Biodata, {
  foreignKey: "userId",
  as: "biodata",
});

module.exports = User;
```

#### What do you expect to happen?

It should not set all foreign keys to null after running sync with options `{ alter: true }`

#### What is actually happening?

`userGroupId` in table `user` is null and `userId` in table `biodata` is also null.

#### Environment

- Sequelize version: ^6.6.5
- Node.js version: 12.9.1
- Dialect: SQLite (SQLite3)

From my issue : https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/13464

anyone can help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after struggling for a couple of days, I managed to resolve it by disabling and re-enabling foreign keys before and after syncing :

```js
await sequelize.query("PRAGMA foreign_keys = false;");
await sequelize
      .sync({ alter: true })
      .then(async (result) => {
        await initDataUserGroup();
        await initDataGateType();
      })
      .catch((errorMessage) => console.error("sync error = ", errorMessage));
await sequelize.query("PRAGMA foreign_keys = true;");
```

Feel free to inform me a better solution than the current one.